# Use Custom Class to Grant Permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am new to android. I am trying to grant permissions from custom class. I have two interfaces and a singleton class, like this

```
public interface RequestPermissionsResultInterface
{
   void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults);
}

public interface PermissionManagerInterface
{
   void onPermissionGranted(String message, int requestCode);
   void onPermissionDenied(String message, int requestCode);
}

public class PermissionManager
{
    private Activity mActivity;
    private static volatile PermissionManagerInterface mManagerInterface;


    public static PermissionManager getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (mPermissionManager == null)
        {
           synchronized (PermissionManager.class)
           {
               if (mPermissionManager == null)
               {
                  mPermissionManager = new PermissionManager(context);
               }
           }
        }
        return mPermissionManager;
    }

    private boolean isReadStorageAllowed()
    {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return ((result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
    }

    public RequestPermissionsResultInterface askPermission(
        Activity mActivity,
        String permissionName,
        final PermissionManagerInterface managerInterface,
        final int requestCode)
    {
        boolean isReadExternalStorageAllowed = isReadStorageAllowed();
        if(isReadExternalStorageAllowed == false)
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity, permissionName))
            {
                 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
                builder.setMessage("Please allow all permissions in App Settings for additional functionality.");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        managerInterface.onPermissionGranted("Permission Granted", requestCode);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        managerInterface.onPermissionDenied("Permission Denied", requestCode);
                    }
                });

                final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
        else managerInterface.onPermissionGranted("Permission Already Granted", requestCode);
    }
 }
```

And here is how I use this class in MainActivity

```
 PermissionManager permManager = PermissionManager.getInstance();
 permManager.askPermission(
            MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            mPermissionManagerInterface,               // assume this exists
            EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
```

Again.... it is not persistent. If I give permission, then stop and restart the app again....this is asking me for permission again. What could be wrong?? Thanks

Comment: If you are new to Android, try doing it the documented way before you get ahead of yourself by trying to put your own spin on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to go the "custom" method, you still need to handle certain things.

1. `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` is only true if you have previously requested a permission and was denied it. You seem to be using it to display a dialog saying "please grant permissions" but not actually asking the system to show the permission request dialog.
2. The command to actually request permissions is `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`. Can't see this in your code. The user cannot grant permission unless you actually ask for them.
3. `onRequestPermissionsResult` is where you should be calling your interface to say permission was granted.

Full instructions are in the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thanks...that worked. However that was only part of the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: If you look again, you will see in point 2 I stated you were not requesting permissions so I did indeed give you a complete answer. Please Accept\vote up the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers This is not a forum. Thank you

Comment: Yes. In a sense, your answer is complete. I was (wrongly) expecting that my custom dialog will be able to handle that. It was not. If I use my custom dialog, I still have to request permissions through ActivityCompat.requestPermissions. So I end up showing TWO dialog boxes (which is annoying knowing my custom dialog is worthless). I hope I am making sense. Still full credit to you. I don't have 15 reputations so can not upvote.

Comment: You don't need rep to accept an answer. Please learn how the site works. I posted a link to help you. You gain rep by accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

From Android Documentation

> Note: When your app calls requestPermissions(), the system shows a standard dialog box to the user. Your app cannot configure or alter that dialog box.

I was trying to grant permission through custom dialog which was never going to work. This was only part of the problem.

I was not requesting permission in custom dialog code section (which would have been bad because I end up showing 2 dialogs: standard + my custom dialog). So I remove my custom dialog and stick to the standard one.

Kudos goes to **kuffs** because s/he put me in the right direction.